# Simular display 7 segmentos en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola necesito simular un display de 7 segmentos en python, doy un ejemplo del resultado que debo obtener,

[image: Este es el resultado que debo obtener]

mi codigo es este:

```
display = ["""###
# #
# #
# #
###"""]

display.insert(1,"""  #
  #
  #
  #
  #""")

display.insert(2, """###
  #
###
#
###""")

display.insert(3, """###
  #
###
  #
###""")
display.insert(4, """# #
# #
###
  #
  #""")
display.insert(5, """###
#
###
  #
###""")
display.insert(6, """###
#
###
# #
###""")
display.insert(7, """###
  #
  #
  #
  #""")
display.insert(8, """###
# #
###
# #
###""")
display.insert(9, """###
# #
###
  #
###""")


x = int(input("Por favor inserta un numero: "))
print(display[x])
```

> a la hora de ejecutarlo, solo obtengo un número como resultado, no se como hacer para que me muestre mas digitos en pantalla en la misma linea, ya que he hecho que me muestre mas digitos, pero me los muestra uno encima del otro

[ACTUALIZACION]

@abulafia modifique mi codigo e hice el ciclo `for`, no me queda muy claro como hacer para concatenar el espacio y añadir mas digitos al resultado, copio el codigo que tengo:

```
digit =[[
'###',
'# #',
'# #',
'# #',
'###',
],
[
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
],
[
'###',
'  #',
'###',
'#  ',
'###',
],
[
'###',
'  #',
'###',
'  #',
'###',
],
[
'# #',
'# #',
'###',
'  #',
'  #',
],
[
'###',
'#  ',
'###',
'  #',
'###',
],
[
'###',
'#  ',
'###',
'# #',
'###',
],
[
'###',
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
],
[
'###',
'# #',
'###',
'# #',
'###',
],
[
'###',
'# #',
'###',
'  #',
'###',
]]
numero = int(input("ingresa un numero:"))

for i in range(5):
    renglon = ""
    renglon = (digit[numero][i])
    print(renglon)
```

[ACTUALIZACIÓN]

Agregue el otro ciclo for, pero solo me funciona con un digito si agrego mas de 1 me imprime caracteres en desorde.

```
for i in range(5):
  for cifra in numero:
    cifra= int(cifra)
    renglon = (digit[cifra][i])
    renglon += " "
    renglon += (digit[cifra][i])
    print(renglon)
```

Comment: @abulafia me podrías dar un ejemplo, no se como hacer la iteración por renglones

Comment: He añadido un pseudocódigo a la pregunta. Los bucles de ese pseudocódigo se traducen a bucles `for` en python. Sigue intentándolo...

Comment: Además del ejemplo que te dio abulafia, una buena opción es guardar el display de los números en listas (cada elemento es un renglon). Con `zip()` y un `for` se consigue fácil. Saludos.

Comment: @abulafia modifique mi codigo e hice el ciclo `for`, no me queda muy claro como hacer para concatenar el espacio y añadir mas digitos al resultado, copio el codigo que tengo:

Comment: El código que has pegado tiene el ciclo for para recorrer los renglones. Pero dentro de ese ciclo necesitas otro ciclo for que recorra las cifras que quieres mostrar. La concatenación se hace con `renglon = renglon + lo_que_sea`. Para poder recorrer el número dado cifra a cifra, quita el `int()` alrededor del input. De ese modo `numero` ya no será un dato numérico, sino una cadena. De ese modo podrás hacer un `for cifra in numero` y obtener cada cifra separadamente. Entonces podrás hacer `int(cifra)` para obtener el entero que usarás como primer índice en `digitos`

Comment: @abulafia hice el otro ciclo ```for``` pero no se como hacer que identifique los numeros ingresados de forma individual, solo me funcionan cuando ingreso un digito, pero mas de ahi no

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta explicando qué estaba mal en tu for, y dando ya una solución.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No te voy a dar la solución completa para darte la oportunidad de pegarte un poco más con el ejercicio. Te daré algunas pistas y cuando lo hayas intentado, si lo consigues puedes publicar tu propia respuesta y si no lo consigues puedes preguntar de nuevo indicando hasta dónde conseguiste llegar.

La idea es que guardes el "diseño" de los dígitos como sub-listas. Es decir, que cada dígito sea en realidad una lista que contenga lo que debe mostrarse en cada línea.

De este modo la lista de dígitos no sería una lista de cadenas, como en tu caso, sino una lista de listas. Por ejemplo, comenzaría así:

```
display = [
[
'###',
'# #',
'# #',
'# #',
'###',
],
[
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
'  #',
],
[
'###',
'  #',
'###',
'#  ',
'###',
],
...
]
```

De este modo `digitos[0]` es la lista:

```
[
'###',
'# #',
'# #',
'# #',
'###',
]
```

y cada elemento de esta lista es un "renglón" de los que hay que mostrar en la salida.

A la hora de mostrar un número de varias cifras como el 120, tendrás este número como cadena `"120"`. Se trata de crear uno a uno los cinco "renglones" siguientes:

```
  #  ###  ###  
  #    #  # #  
  #  ###  # #  
  #  #    # #  
  #  ###  ###
```

Fijate que el primer renglón de la salida buscada está compuesta por el primer renglón de `digitos[1]` y el de `digitos[2]` y el de `digitos[0]`. Por tanto ese primer renglón de la salida se construye concatenando (separado por espacios) los elementos `digitos[1][0]`, `digitos[2][0]` y `digitos[0][0]`

De forma análoga el siguiente renglón saldrá de concatenar `digitos[1][1]`, `digitos[2][1]` y `digitos[0][1]` y así sucesivamente.

En definitiva, hay que iterar 5 veces (pues son 5 rengones) y en cada iteración `i` concatenar los elementos de `digitos[x][i]`, siendo el primer índice `x` el que corresponde a cada uno de los dígitos. Por tanto se requieren dos bucles anidados: el externo para recorrer los renglones y el interno para recorrer los dígitos a mostrar.

### Pseudocódigo

```
para cada renglón de 0 a 4 (son 5):
  renglon = "" 
  para cada digito del numero:
     concatenar al renglón el elemento digitos[digito][renglon]
     concatenar al renglón un espacio en blando
  imprimir renglón
```

## Solución

He visto en las ampliaciones a la pregunta que ya casi lo tenías. Este era tu último intento:

```
for i in range(5):
  for cifra in numero:
    cifra= int(cifra)
    renglon = (digit[cifra][i])
    renglon += " "
    renglon += (digit[cifra][i])
    print(renglon)
```

Sin embargo no está del todo bien. Si intentas "ejecutarlo en tu cabeza", verás que para cada renglón se hace lo siguiente:

- Se recorre cada cifra del número, y para cada cifra

  - Se crea un renglón tomando la fila adecuada de esa cifra
  - Se añade un espacio
  - Se vuelve a añadir la misma fila de la misma cifra (?)
  - Se imprime el renglón (?)

Los dos últimos pasos marcados con (?) están mal, pues no sólo estás añadiendo dos veces el mismo "segmento", sino que además la impresión del renglón la haces dentro del bucle interno, es decir, ese "renglón mal" que has creado se imprimer para cada dígito.

La idea era en cambio:

- Para cada renglón

  - Inicializar un renglón como vacío
  - Crear el contenido de ese renglón
  - Imprimirlo

Y es el segundo paso "crear el contenido del renglón" el que necesita otro bucle:

- para cada cifra
- Añadir al renglón el trozo necesario de esa cifra
- Y un espacio

En este bucle interno no se imprime nada, nos limitamos a crear el renglón, que será impreso una vez terminado desde el bucle externo.

Así que la solución, tomando como punto de partida tu último código y modificándolo adecuadamente, quedará así:

```
numero = input("Dame un numero: ")
for i in range(5):
  renglon = ""                   # Empezar con renglón vacío
  for cifra in numero:           # Crear el renglón
    cifra= int(cifra)            #    Recorriendo cada cifra
    renglon += digit[cifra][i]   #    y añadiéndola al renglón
    renglon += " "               #    mas un espacio en blanco
  print(renglon)                 # Imprimir el renglón creado
```