# ¿Por qué no me sobreescribe el valor de la cadena anterior?

Tags: python

He desarrollado el ejercicio del display siete segmentos a partir de la solución que da @abulafia en una respuesta; pero más allá de hacer el ejercicio quiero entender cómo funciona cada línea: en ese sentido no entiendo por qué al parámetro "renglon" se le asigna dos valores seguidos y aún así funciona correctamente, agrega el espacio. ¿Por qué pasa eso y no sobreescribe (borra) lo asignado en la línea previa?

```
for i in range(5):
     renglon=""
     for cifra in numero:
         cifra = int(bits) 
         renglon += Lista[bits][i]
         renglon += "  " #¿Por que este NO sobre escribe el valor que tenia de la anterior linea?
     print(renglon)
```

No sé si me he hecho entender.
[Simular display 7 segmentos en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372931/simular-display-7-segmentos-en-python)

Comment: Buen día, en ambas líneas se utiliza el [operador de asignación](https://ellibrodepython.com/operadores-asignacion) `+=`, es decir la línea `renglon += Lista[bits][i]` se traduce a `renglon = renglon + Lista[bits][i]` y `renglon += "  "` sería `renglon = renglon + "  "`. Es decir, en ambas líneas tomas el valor actual de la variable y le agregas algo, no lo sobreescribes, si fuera únicamente `=` entonces sí se sobreescribiría.

Comment: En lo posible, pulsá en [edit] y colocá el enlace a la respuesta a la que hacés referencia.

Comment: ¿Eso es todo el código en cuestión? Porque veo varios errores aparte del que comentas, cómo que un entero no es iterable, no se define la variable "numero" ni "bits".

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta HeytalePazguato, hay que diferenciar los distintos operadores de asignación, el operador "básico" es el =, que efectivamente, sobrescribe el valor de la variable:

```py
a = 'texto '
a = 'más texto'
print(a)  # más texto
```

Por otro lado, tenemos otros operadores de asignación, que no sobrescriben, sino que modifican, y son:

```
+=
-=
*=
/=
%=
//=
**=
&=
|=
^=
>>=
<<=
```

Cada uno de estos operadores, aplica una operación al contenido original de la variable y a la "parte izquierda", cuyo resultado almacena en la propia variable, más en concreto, en tu caso:

```py
renglon += Lista[bits][i]
renglon += "  "
```

El operador `+=` suma el contenido de la variable a la parte izquierda y el resultado lo asigna a la variable. Sería equivalente a `renglon = renglon + "  "`.

Como son strings, la suma de dos strings es su concatenación.

Comment: Gracias me quedo super claro.

Comment: Si consideras que esta es la respuesta a tu pregunta por favor márcala como tal, de esta forma cuando este post sea visitado se puede ver mas claro que fue la solución.